# Having problems replacing a regex substring from string

Tags: objective-c, regex, string

I'm currently just trying to grab a substring and replace it using the following method:

```
-(void)deleteTag:(UIButton *)sender
{
    //grab sender and delete
    [sender removeFromSuperview];

    NSString *stringToReplace = [[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"\\b",sender.titleLabel.text,@" ",@"\\b", nil] componentsJoinedByString:@""];
    NSString *catchString = postTagField.text;
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:stringToReplace options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:&error];
    NSString *modifiedString = [regex stringByReplacingMatchesInString:catchString options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [catchString length]) withTemplate:@""];
    NSLog(@"%@", modifiedString);


    //NSString *tempString = [postTagField.text stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:stringToReplace withString:@""];
    postTagField.text = modifiedString;

    [tagArray removeObject:sender];
    lastTagArrayCount--;
}
```

So what happens is.. the user types "This is " in an `UITextField`, I then create my regex with the 4th line: **stringToReplace** which places a **word boundary** formatting on the beginning and end to make sure that I delete the exact word along with the space trailing it.

I then attempt to replace postTagField.text with *modifiedString* but *modifiedString* always *upon breakpoint* ends up being "This is ", as if the regex method `stringByReplacingMatchesInString:` never correctly replaces the match(there should only be one) and returns modifiedString to be the exact same as catchString.

The correct result should be **catchString** minus the string captured in **stringToReplace**. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Regex backslashes should be doubled, if i recall correctly: `stringToReplace = [NSString format:@"\\b %@ \\b", sender.titleLabel.text]`

Comment: Unfortunately I just tried that and *modifiedString* still ends up being "This is "

Comment: also `range:NSMakeRange(0, [stringToReplace length])` - range here specifies `sorce`'s string length where replaces should be, not `regex`-ps... so `range:NSMakeRange(0, [catchString length])`. ... Or you''l end up with regexp searching in `@"As said, Thi"` - portion of `@"As said, This is an opportunity"` source string, which will never match `@"\\b This is \\b"` pattern

Comment: Okay that's a great point, just used `catchString length` instead, still does not create a new string that replaces the matching string with null by `@""`. I can update this to reflect what I am now trying.

Comment: Then, something wrong with yours regexp. Try `[NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"is" ...` pattern, then `@"\\bis"`, and so on, debugging it step-by step...

Comment: also, just a suggestion, but `[[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"\\b",sender.titleLabel.text,@" ",@"\\b", nil] componentsJoinedByString:@""];` construct is _really_ creepy and _hard-to-read-and-understand-quickly_. Use `+[NSString format:]` instead...

Comment: Alright that debugging strategy just totally worked... making stringToReplace set like this worked out `NSString *stringToReplace = [[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"\\b",sender.titleLabel.text,@" ", nil] componentsJoinedByString:@""];`

Comment: *thumbs up Glad it helped =)